# how to calculate age form list of dates in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, calculator, converters

How to calculate age from list. Is this possible?

```
name= ['Jonas','Miko','Jenelyn']
birthdate=['02/26/2000','12/02/2001','04/21/1999']

 expected output:
student Jonas age is 20 y.o
student Miko age is 19 y.o
student Jenelyn age is 21 y.o
```

Comment: yes it's possible. did you try anything?

Comment: yes but always give error 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: try `strptime` ;-) remember: the 'p' is for parse as in 'parse string to datetime'

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, yes it's possible.

Comment: thank you guys for all the help.  I'm new in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to format the dates appropriately, so research the datetime date function and figure out where to go from here.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

for n, bday in zip(name, birthdate):
  age = (today - date(bday)).years
  print("Student ", n, "age is ", age, "years old.")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm researching some possible solution but I will start on this.